# How to force link to open in new window (not new tab) in Google Chrome on a Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, tabs

Under Mac, how can I get links (boh from web pages within Chrome AND from external apps) to open in a new window rather than in a new tab in the active window?

This has been answered for Windows, but I cannot find a solution for Mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hold the SHIFT key and left-click the link; the link will open in a new window.

Comment: That works inside Chrome, but not for a link in an external application like Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script to do this, then I set my default application in system preferences to this script for web links, works for me but not reliably and I welcome any/all better answers. I haven't found anything better in the years I've been using this though

http://smoove-operator.blogspot.com/2011/06/open-links-from-external-applications.html

Comment: Try to post excerpts or code from a link as they can sometimes go down or disappear

Comment: It is true those sometimes go down, however that's my own blog, so I exercise a bit more control. That said, it doesn't work very well in OSX 10.8.x and no one is sure how to make it work better so this isn't really a solved problem yet (see comments on my blog entry if you want the gory details...)